# Transform XML through XSLT while distinguishing different values in same node

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to transform this XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ens:query xmlns:ens="urn:example.com">
            <ens:queryString>Select Example</ens:queryString>
            <ens:param>
                <ens:name>maxRows</ens:name>
                <ens:value>123</ens:value>
            </ens:param>
            <ens:param>
                <ens:name>startingRow</ens:name>
                <ens:value>456</ens:value>
            </ens:param>
        </ens:query>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

into this:

```
<queryParameters>
    <maxRows>123</maxRows>
    <startingRow>456</startingRow>
</queryParameters>
```

I know how to copy nodes, but the namespace prefix "ens" and the fact that ens:param has 2 entries confuses the hell out of me. I tried to adress the single nodes though 1 and 2, but to no avail. I simply have no idea how to reference and distinguish them properly at the same time. Also I need to create node names from node values. Could someone help me about his issue?

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems quite simple, not sure why you're having such problems with it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ens="urn:example.com"
exclude-result-prefixes="soapenv ens">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/soapenv:Envelope">
    <queryParameters>
        <xsl:for-each select="soapenv:Body/ens:query/ens:param">
            <xsl:element name="{ens:name}">
                <xsl:value-of select="ens:value"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </queryParameters>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But do note that this will fail if the value of `ens:name` is not a valid XML element name.

Comment: Maybe i overthought this, but i could not figure out how to properly iterate over the nodes. I need to look for he simple solutions first i guess. Thank you so much for the help!